# How can I create a calendar input similar to the photo?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, storybook

I am trying to implement a form in React and I am building elements separately using storybook. I am trying to implement a calendar input using Just CSS and HTML that allows users to select a start date and end date with the option of adding plus or minus days (1, 3, 7 etc.)

[image: Calendar input (open)]

```js
// /** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'

interface InputProps {
  size?: 'small' | 'medium' | 'large'
  variant: 'location' | 'calendar'
  type: string
  placeholder: string
  icon: string
  alt: string
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({
  size,
  variant = 'location',
  type,
  placeholder,
  icon,
  alt,
  children,
}: InputProps) => {
  
  return (
    <div className="storybook-input-container">
      {icon !== null && icon !== '' && (
        <img
          src={icon}
          alt={alt}
          className={['storybook-icon', `storybook-icon--${variant}`].join(' ')}
        />
      )}
      <input
        type={type}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        className={[
          'storybook-input',
          `storybook-input--${size}`,
          `storybook-input--${variant}`,
          `storybook-input--${type}`,
        ].join(' ')}
      ></input>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```css
.storybook-input {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8ed;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Nunito Sans;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 150.04%;
}

.storybook-input--calendar::placeholder {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.storybook-icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.storybook-icon--location {
  top: 50%;
  left: 155px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The calendar options available online are third-party styling libraries but I am not using any third-party libraries such as Tailwind in this project.